# Tracking Runtime Complexity

Tags: sorting, big-o

What is the best way to calculate runtime complexity for any method? It's easy to do that for non-recursive methods, like bubblesort

```
outer-for loop
{
   inner-for loop
      {
           compare and exchange
      }
}
```

To check, the best way is to put a counter in the inner-most loop. But, when the method is recursive, where should I put the counter, for instance merge sort,

```
sort(int[] array){

    left = first-half
    right = second-half

    sort(left);
    sort(right);
   ret merge(left, right);

}

merge(int[] left, right)
{
    count = length(left + right);
    int[] result;
    loop-count-times
    {
       compare and put in result;
    }

  return result;
}
```

Since this is merge sort, the big(o) is o(n log n), so an array of 100 ints should return a big-o of 200 exactly. Where will the counter go? If I put it at the top of sort(..), I get an average of 250, 280, 300, which should be wrong. What is the best place for this counter?

references:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergesort

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have slightly misunderstood the concept of Big-O notation. If the complexity is O(n log n) and the value of n is 100, there is no strict rule that the program should execute exactly in Big-O of 200. It only gives us an upper bound. For example consider selection sort with an O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity. Even if n is 100 the counter set inside the inner loop will not give you 100<sup>2</sup> as result if the list is already sorted. So in your case what you get as answer (250, 280, 300, etc.) is perfectly valid. Because all the answers are limited by k times n log n, where k is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: I agree with both of those replies, however, according to Wikipedia (article referenced), the Worst Case for a Merge Sort is n*log n. I assume, by that, that every case will yield a n*log n complexity. Quicksort, on the other hand, can vary between n*log n and n^2 (worst case), however, Merge Sort does not.

Comment: If a function f(n) is O(n log n), then the time taken by f(n) is less than or equal to (k * n * log n), where k is a constant. You didn't consider this constant k in your analysis.

Comment: Oh yes, that's a good point. I forgot about that, complexity looks right now.

Answer (score 2):

> Since this is merge sort, the big(o) is o(n log n), so an array of 100 ints should return a big-o of 200 exactly.

Not even close to right.

Computational complexity denoted using the big Ordo-notation does **not** tell you how many steps/computational operations will be executed exactly. There's a reason it's called *asymptotic* and not *identical* complexity: it only gives you a function that approaches (more precisely, gives a higher bound on) the running time of the algorithm **with regards to the size of the input.**

So `O(n log n)` doesn't mean that for 100 elements, 200 operations will be performed (*how come, by the way, that the base of the logarithm must be 10?*), it tells you that if you increase the size of your input, the (average-case) running time will be proportional to the number of pieces of input data added, multiplied by the logarithm of the number of this additional data.

To the point: if you want to count the number of calls to a recursive function, you should put the counter in as an argument, like this:

```
void merge_sort(int array[], size_t length, int *counter)
{
    (*counter)++;
    // apply the algorithm to `array`:
    merge_sort(array, length, counter);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
int num_calls = 0;
merge_sort(array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]), &num_calls);
printf("Called %d times\n", num_calls);
```